# Crop image before uploading to carrierwave rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jcrop

Solution that is pretty close to what I want but not really the solution: http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?autoplay=true

What I want :-

1. Open a small popup dialog that tells user to crop their image when the 'select image' input button is clicked.
2. On cropping and closing the dialog the cropped image must be attached to the input field
3. In submitting the form the form, cropped image should be saved with the user.

Some approaches that I considered but don't solve my problem :-

1. Preview selected file as blob in the image tag and send it with the form somehow
2. Use cropper.js or similar library and submit crop image on next page
   after submitting the form.

My Devise edit form:-

```
.col-md-12
  .col-md-4
  .col-md-4
  %center
    %h2 Edit Your Profile
    = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_[enter image description here][1]name), html: {method: :put, multipart: true}) do |f|
      = devise_error_messages!
      .field
        - if current_user.avatar.url.present?
          = image_tag(current_user.avatar.url, id: 'preview_img', style: "width: 10rem; height: 10rem;padding-bottom: 1rem;")
        = f.file_field :avatar
        = f.hidden_field :avatar_cache
      %br/
      .field
        = f.label :email
        %br/
        = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"
      - if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation?
        %div
          Currently waiting confirmation for: #{resource.unconfirmed_email}
      .field
        = f.label :password
        %i (leave blank if you don't want to change it)
        %br/
        = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control"
      .field
        = f.label :password_confirmation
        %br/
        = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control"
      .field
        = f.label :current_password
        %i (we need your current password to confirm your changes)
        %br/
        = f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control"
      %br/
      .actions
        %center
          = f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary"
          / %br/
          %small= link_to "Delete Account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

[want something like this to open up when I click upload image button and attach it to input field on clicking submit so it can be updated with the rails form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nGhP.png)

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to store the offset and dimensions of your 'crop' window and submit that to the server along with the image and just have the server crop the image before saving it to disk? Doing this in the browser sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: You seem to make sense. I was actually thinking of making a bootstrap modal with jcrop for the image. And then send it to the server with the cropped dimensions as shown in the rail-cast. I will inspect the railcast in more detail and see where I can get with it.